# parsing xml file won't work

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I have an object constructor which uses an xmlfile to set the properties of the method. The constructor accesses it by

```
$this->xml_file = simplexml_load_file('xml/settings.xml');
```

This is how the xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<settings>
   <contents>
      <content>
         <item>a</item>
         <title>A</title>
         <keywords></keywords>
      </content>
      <content>
         <item>b</item>
         <title>B</title>
         <keywords></keywords>
      </content>
      <content>
         <item>c</item>
         <title>C</title>
         <keywords></keywords>
      </content>
   <errors_escape>
      <error_escape>one</error_escape>
      <error_escape>two</error_escape>
      <error_escape>three</error_escape>
   </errors_escape>
</settings>
```

I'd like to create two arrays with this information. The should look like:

```
protected $all_settings = array(
         array('item' => 'a', 'title' => 'A', 'keywords' => ''),
         array('item' => 'b', 'title' => 'B', 'keywords' => ''),
         array('item' => 'c', 'title' => 'C', 'keywords' => ''),
      );
protected $errors_escape = array('one', 'two', 'three');
```

I've tried and read different questions on this topic, but I can't do anything but create arrays where it says

```
[title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => A
                )
```

or

```
[title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )
```

Comment: Your XML is missing a `</contents>`; Is that a typo or an actual error in your file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your missing `</contents>` is placed as below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<settings>
   <contents>
      <content>
         <item>a</item>
         <title>A</title>
         <keywords></keywords>
      </content>
      <content>
         <item>b</item>
         <title>B</title>
         <keywords></keywords>
      </content>
      <content>
         <item>c</item>
         <title>C</title>
         <keywords></keywords>
      </content>
   </contents> <!-- missing -->
   <errors_escape>
      <error_escape>one</error_escape>
      <error_escape>two</error_escape>
      <error_escape>three</error_escape>
   </errors_escape>
</settings>
```

You can do something like this:

```php
$this->all_settings=array();
$this->error_escape=array();
foreach($this->xml_file->contents->content as $node)
{
    $this->all_settings[]=array("item"=>strval($node->item),"title"=>strval($node->title),"keywords"=>strval($node->keywords));
}
foreach($this->xml_file->errors_escape->error_escape as $node)
{
    $this->error_escape[]=strval($node);
}
//print_r($this->all_settings);
//print_r($this->error_escape);
```

[Online demo](http://3v4l.org/MutNG)

The two debug `print_r` outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item] => a
            [title] => A
            [keywords] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item] => b
            [title] => B
            [keywords] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item] => c
            [title] => C
            [keywords] => 
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about strval() so that is what I needed.